# Page is redirecting to my php script from form

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I am trying to make a login system with php but i cant figure out why my form is just redirecting me to the script file when i click on my login button. it works fine on my sign up form. everything seems to work exept its redirecting me to the script file. My php file that contains my form: https://codepen.io/hubbe-andersson/pen/yGOPoM

EDIT: I have put my phpscript into my header.php instead and now im getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in chrome what is caussing this?

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['login-sub'])) {
        require 'databash.php';

        $username = $_POST['mailname'];
        $password = $_POST{'pwd'};

        if(empty($username) || empty($password)) {
            header("Location: index.php?error=tommarutor");
            exit();
        } else {

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE uidUsers=? OR emailUsers=?";
            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
            if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                header("Location: index.php?error=sqlerror");
                exit();
            } else {

                mysqli_stmt_bind_parem($stmt, "ss", $username, $username);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                $resultat = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
                if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultat)) {
                    $checkpwd = password_verify($password, $row['pwdUsers']);
                    if($checkpwd == false) {
                        header("Location: index.php?error=fellosenord");
                        exit();
                    }
                    else if ($checkpwd == true) {
                        seassion_start();
                        $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['idUsers'];
                        $_SESSION['userUid'] = $row['uidUsers'];
                        header("Location: index.php?login=lyckades");
                        exit();

                    }
                    else {
                        header("Location: index.php?error=fellosenord");
                        exit();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    header("Location: index.php?error=ingenanvandare");
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
       header("Location: index.php");
       exit();
    }
```

Comment: @TarangP what do you mean?

Comment: you get any parameters on url like ?error=fellosenord  ?

Comment: @TarangP aha no the thing is it just redirect me from my index.php file that contains my form with the login. it just redirect me to my script file

Comment: Can you post the HTML for your form?

Comment: @Second2None yeah i am on my way was just going to do that haha

Comment: https://codepen.io/hubbe-andersson/pen/yGOPoM there you go @Second2None

Comment: Put it in the question, not another site.

Comment: Can you also post any response from the loginfile.php page? I assume the php code above is from loginfile.php?

Comment: You have a typo here: `mysqli_stmt_bind_parem`. `parem` should be `param`.

Comment: @Second2None what do you mean haha sorry im really new to php and yes it is from loginfile.php

Comment: @param thank you i will se if that will do anything :) btw i tried but i was not able to get in the code here thats why i uploaded it to codepen Edit: thanks for pointing it out it dident fix the problem tho:)

Comment: Looks like Barmar may have found your issue, I meant when are redirected what isthe HTML code of loginfile.php. It's not completely executing which could mean there is a fatal/non fatal error somewhere. check out this link for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495098/fatal-vs-not-fatal-error-in-php

Comment: You also have a spelling mistake here: seassion_start(); should be session_start();

Comment: oh i think i have ben awake for to long haha thank you. it did not fix the problem tho but thank you alot @Second2None

Comment: Oh nvm that actully did help thank you man you helped me so i can finally go to sleep :) @Second2None

Comment: @Second2None it fixed so i actully got logged in to the website but im still getting redirected to the script file tho

Comment: @Second2None it is like my header dosent work or something

Comment: Yeah looks like it might be a header issue, when you get redirected, is there any HTML displayed? Header won't work if html has already been sent, so if you have scripts above this PHP code for instance <html> or anything that isn't PHP it won't work. Try making sure your php errors are turned on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060/showing-all-errors-and-warnings/5438125

Comment: @Second2None no i  dont have any html in my scriptfile at all. thank you i will read that Edit: aha i dont know if i could change that if its turend off im using my schools server

Comment: Having your errors on while developing/debugging can help a lot it would of picked up on those misspelled functions.

Comment: @second2None yea but i dont think i can change that on my schools server haha

Comment: https://webbkurs.ei.hv.se/~sean0005/php/ @Second2None here is the website btw if it could help in anyway haha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185284/discussion-between-second2none-and-sebastian-andersson).

Answer (score 0):

line 6 error:         use `[...]` instead of `{...}`

Look at the middle code block. Everything inside that focuses on determining which error the results will return, so establish that in your `$_SESSION` data and then redirect `header("Location....` once. Most mistakes are little ones like the line 6 error, make a habit of adding `// comments` to your code so that it's easier to sort out the lines and sections of your code.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['login-sub'])) {   
        require 'databash.php';

        $username = $_POST['mailname'];
        $password = $_POST['pwd'];

        if(empty($username) || empty($password)) {    
            header("Location: index.php?error=tommarutor");
            exit();
        } else {      

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE uidUsers=? OR emailUsers=?";
            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
            if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {    
                header("Location: index.php?error=sqlerror");
                exit();
            } else {        

                mysqli_stmt_bind_parem($stmt, "ss", $username, $username);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                $resultat = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
```

---

```
                if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultat)) {
                    $checkpwd = password_verify($password,  $row['pwdUsers']);
                    if($checkpwd == false) {
                        session_start();
                        $_SESSION['error']="fellosenord";
                    }  else if ($checkpwd == true) {
                        seassion_start();
                        $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['idUsers'];
                        $_SESSION['userUid'] = $row['uidUsers'];
                        $_SESSION['login']="lyckades");
                    } else {
                        session_start();
                        $_SESSION['error']="fellosenord";
                    }   //end checkpwd
                } else {    //  if fetch fails, send error
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['error']="ingenanvandare";
                }   //  end fetch
                header("Location: index.php");
```

---

```
            }   // end if stmt exists
        }   // end not empty input
    } else { // if isset isn't set...
       header("Location: index.php");
       exit();
    } //   end isset
php database mysqli
```

Your `index.php` page need to start off by looking for the query string passed via `$_SESSIONS` to prevent people from trying to access the page without the related form.

```
session_start();
if ( empty($_SESSION['id']) ) {   // no session info...
...
} else {
...
}
```

Ask your teacher to explain finding errors and solving problems so you can learn what to look for.